# issue with bitmap android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i can get Image from URL and display it in imageview... now i have try through this code....\

**Code**

```
**
    private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    /*
     * private class FetchImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
     * 
     * @Override protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) { Bitmap b =
     * null; try { b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new
     * URL(arg0[0]).getContent()); } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     * e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
     * return b; } }
     */

    private class NearByScreenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        Bitmap BMP = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");

            this.dialog.show();
            // put your code which preload with processDialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
                bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
                BMP = LoadImage(strURL, bmOptions);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ERROR" + e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e(TAG, "BMP is :: ---" + BMP);
                image.setImageBitmap(BMP);

            }
        }
    }
```

**oncreate ::**

```
image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            Log.i(TAG, "item.getImageURL()" + item.getImageURL());
            strURL = item.getImageURL();
            new NearByScreenTask().execute();
```

**UPDATE2**

```
    BMP = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL(strURL).openStream());
image.setImageBitmap(BMP);
```

But BMP getting me Null when i have print it in logcat.i  have also check image url and its going good in browser. but some critical issue raise over here so it getting NULL , can you please help me out this....

Comment: 228x280 px size of image and it is not fix becase any image come with any size\

Comment: @VipulShah Please check it i have update it

Comment: You should be logging the exceptions using Android's log libraries. Are there any exceptions in Logcat?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu No there are no error log in logcat

Comment: "any size" may not be a good thing, as you could end up with OutOfMermoryError

Comment: Have you debugged through it? What's the response from the HTTP connection?

Comment: Are you sure `OpenHttpConnection(URL)` doesn't return null?

Comment: I think method OpenHttpConnection is having some exception. please debug it and you will come to know from your side.

Comment: @Dalmas Please check my new update it getting me output in emulator nut not in real device (odd)

Comment: @AlexFlorescu Please check my new update it getting me output in emulator nut not in real device (odd)

Comment: @AleksG Please check my new update it getting me output in emulator nut not in real device (odd)

Comment: @VipulShah Please check my new update it getting me output in emulator nut not in real device (odd)

Comment: did you include internet permission?\]

Comment: Try and print (i.e. Log) the interesting values in doInBackground. So let's see what BMP gets set to after LoadImage. Also let's see if the strUrl is correct and then use that info to narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stated here](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/#comment-747), you should try to change your `OpenHttpConnection()` method to :

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(strURL));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    return bufHttpEntity.getContent();
}
```

Comment: Please check my new update it getting me output in emulator nut not in real device (odd)

Answer (score 0):

Try this library for async image loader.

There is number of example code & library available some of them are as below

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList